# In loop condition: why is strlen() called every time, but vector.size() gets called only once?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void f(const char* s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        printf("%c ", s[i]);
    }
}

void g(const vector<int>& v) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Compile link: https://godbolt.org/z/PCi5yg

You will see the assembly code:

- In function `f()`, `strlen(s)` gets called every time;
- But in function `g()`, `v.size()` gets called only once.

Why is that?

The parameters are const, and they didn't change parameter in the inner loop.

Comment: Well, the vector is a `const`, but `strlen` is not const aware, and `s` is not const.

Comment: It would be possible to use `for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)` in the code scanning the C-style string, evading all use of `strlen()`.

Comment: Remember, `strlen` has to access each character in a string until a terminating nul character is found.  This can be very inefficient if the C-Style string doesn't change within the loop.  A `std::vector` may store its size in a member variable and thus can quickly return the size; similarly with `std::string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the generated assembly. It's not that the vector's size is assumed unchanged, it's just that the call to `v.size()` is inlined. The vector's size is still computed anew every loop iteration and loaded into `rax`.

The `const` qualifier only prevents the functions `f` and `g` from modifying the object they refer to. It does not mean they can assume the object is truly immutable and cannot change in size. The compiler has to assume that non-inline functions could be changing the vector, and that includes `printf`.  So the function has to re-compute the vector's size in order to be correct.

You can further convince yourself that the size is re-computed, even with optimization, by [turning off inlining (`-fno-inline`)](https://godbolt.org/z/jdG9aK). The generated assembly quite clearly demonstrates a call to `vector::size`.

Comment: @Broman - Don't worry about it. West const has misled even the very best at times.

Comment: yes, you are right! I was misinterpreting the generated assembly. As you said: `Another thread of execution theoretically could be changing the vector`, So the compiler doesn't cache the value in most case? we should calculate it before loop? Thank you!

Comment: @HangYuan - Can't tell you what you *should do*. That depends on your application and its needs. But I can tell you that a conforming c++ implementation will try its best to produce correct behavior so long as you write correct programs (by correct I mean, no undefined behavior and such).

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you very much!

Comment: *Another thread of execution theoretically could be changing the vector*.  No, compilers *do* optimize based on *that* being UB ([MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387181)).  But calls to non-inline functions like `printf` can change anything except local state that [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) proves it can't.  If there weren't any non-inline function calls in the loop, alias analysis might be able to prove that it was safe to hoist `strlen` or `v.size()`.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Mmm, yes, side-effects are a more compelling reason. Though on paper a compiler should be able to assume more about a standard library function, no?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, it could in theory, but in practice compilers don't do that except for a few special cases, like treating `memcpy` as `__builtin_memcpy` so they can inline it.  Plus, they have to be able to compile code where you might actually have a `char*` to the stdio buffer for `stdout`, whether that code is in a library (when compiling libc) or in a program that used `setbuffer(3)`.  I forget if gcc will assume that calling libc `memcpy` (if it chooses not to inline) only reads/writes the passed buffers, or if it is still treated as arbitrary.

Comment: You do want correctness even if someone puts a wrapper function (with `LD_PRELOAD` or whatever) around `memcpy` that does arbitrary stuff.  Of course ISO C++ doesn't say it's ok to do that, but real implementations have much higher quality-of-implementation / principle-of-least-surprise than merely "compliant with the ISO C++ standard", because they want to be usable for low-level systems programming.